# How can I expose data from hosted service to a streaming endpoint on interval

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, backgroundworker, webapi, asp.net-core-hosted-services

At the moment I have .NET Core Web API running on a Raspberry Pi, the job of this API is to collect data from a connected device on an interval and save the data to a DB, which is what it does already. I want to take this one step further, and expose an endpoint that returns IAsyncEnumerable as a stream, so that when a get request is sent to this endpoint, the frontend can use the incoming stream to see the data coming from the device in real time, while the data is also being saved to the DB.

At the moment I have a [background service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#backgroundservice-base-class) that runs in the background with a while loop that goes on forever and collects the data from the device and saves it to my DB.

Here is an example of some of the code that is in my background service, collecting data from the device currently.

```
public async Task DoWork(CancellationToken stoppingToken, IModbusFactory _modbusFactory)
{
    var master = _modbusFactory.CreateModbusSerialMaster();
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        executionCount++;
        var watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        try
        {
            if (await _featureManager.IsEnabledAsync("ModbusDeviceConnected", stoppingToken))
            {
                _modbusFactory.OpenPort();

                var intervalDataRecord = MapIntervalDataRecord(master);
                _context.IntervalData.Add(intervalDataRecord);

                // Send off data to controller from here? 

                await _context.SaveChangesAsync(stoppingToken);
            }
            else
            {
                //Mock out some behaviour if no device is connected
                var intervalDataRecord = new IntervalDataRecord();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var logError = _logger.LogErrorAndSave(e, e.Message);
            _context.ErrorLogs.Add(logError);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync(stoppingToken);
        }
        finally
        {
            _modbusFactory.ClosePort();
        }

        watch.Stop();
        _logger.LogInformation(
            "Execution Time: {Time} ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        _logger.LogInformation(
            "Scoped Time Series Service is running. Iteration: {Count}", executionCount);
    }

    master.Dispose();
}
```

And here is a example of what my application layer is doing to send a mocked out stream currently.

```
public class GetIntervalDataFromStream : IStreamRequest<IntervalDataRecord>
{
    
}

public class GetIntervalDataFromStreamHandler : IStreamRequestHandler<GetIntervalDataFromStream, IntervalDataRecord>
{
    public async IAsyncEnumerable<IntervalDataRecord> Handle(GetIntervalDataFromStream request, [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000, cancellationToken);
            yield return new IntervalDataRecord(); 
        }
    }
}
```

So my main question, is how do I get that data from the background service as it comes in, into my application layer?

I'm looking for some advice on a decent design pattern for this, I was thinking of implementing the observable pattern here, so that I can push data into the abyss and whatever is listening could subscribe and forward the data, although I was having some strange side effects using the  [Reactive Extensions](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive) library, and the subscriber receiving tons of random empty objects, which I think was a side effect of the dependency injection of a singleton background service and it being transient in nature.

Comment: not a long of answers coming in so I'll add some vague suggestion. maybe something like SignalR will do what you are looking for?
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/aspnet/signalr

Comment: I need to ask some clarifying questions first. What do you want to happen if there's nobody listening? Do you have any protocol restrictions on the client? SignalR is ideal for these kinds of scenarios, but the answer to the prior questions would change my advice.

Comment: When nobody is listening, the data coming in still needs to be saved to the DB. The result I am working towards, is where the user can easily see historical data in a time series graph fashion, and also see the real time data.

Comment: And no, I don't have any restrictions for protocol.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/background-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0).